# How to display the value for the final tick on axis in D3?

Tags: d3.js, axis

I am using d3.time.scale to generate x-axis, and the domain ranges from 1980 to 2013 (year) 
However, tick value only displays upto 2012, not 2013.

I tried .ticks(), but the final tick value does not display until tick count is 25...

Although I can add the final value by manually increasing the domain upto 2014, is there a way to display the tick value for the last tick?

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale).tickSize(20)

var maxYear = format.parse('2014')

xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([min,max])
    .range([100,width-200])    //domain = [1980 ~ 2013] 


var min = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.Year;              // + operator converts string to number.
})

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.Year;
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried using `.nice()`?

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time_nice

This should do the job:

```
xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([min,max])
    .range([100,width-200])    //domain = [1980 ~ 2013]
    .nice()
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect

Comment: @CodeWhisperer You may be using d3 v4. Terminology is a bit different: `scaleTime` instead of `time.scale`. Function `nice` is still here, have a look at [d3.js v4 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#time_nice)